# How to stop phone ringing when play (speak) caller name and then phone ringing again

Tags: android

I want to speak caller name when phone is ringing. I know how to get caller incoming number with his name

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(incomingNumber)); 
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String [] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            callerName = cursor.getString(0);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Display name: " + callerName);
```

i know how to listen with `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and catch it when phone start ringing.

I also know how to speak caller name with `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` but i am having problem how to stop ringing and play caller name and then start ringing again.

How to stop ringing until caller name is not played? I am searching but i can't find solution.

Comment: You could try muting the RING stream with setStreamMute while your TTS is running. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: Michael I already try this with audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true) and then play TTS but not working. Do you maybe have any idea or example?

Comment: You could also try `setStreamVolume`.  Does your app have the `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission?

Comment: Michael i found the problem. When i use setStreamMute phone stop ringing but when i call for example Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); start ringing again. Why? If i call some bundle then start ringing again ... it start so fast that i didn't found that earlier

Comment: now i use audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI); which woks but when i am calling audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 5, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI); to get notification sound, ringing is also set to on and playing ... Are this two channels the same?

Comment: Not exactly. But there's a table (that you can't change) in the AudioService class which specifies for each stream type whether it should use the volume of another stream. And it just so happens that NOTIFICATION uses the volume of RING.  Could you play the TTS as MUSIC?

Comment: Use AudioFocus listener , where you can stop ringing or pause the ring .

Comment: Michael i will test it. Rahul do you have any example how?

Comment: @mbrc have you tested the method Michael told you? I was trying something similar and setStreamVolume works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to do. Android reference doesn't cover this, but I was testing it for a while and I was able to control ringer volume only at very early stage of a call (before you can hear the sound). Every change you make after it sounds will come to effect just after the call ends (so, with the next call). I don't know what is the behavior of the other streams though, I was only interested in this one (but this doesn't matter I guess because you can't mute STREAM_RING).